# NoSuchFieldError - Is it possible to include both httpclient-4.3.3 jar and httpclient-4.2.5 jar in the same application

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, thrift, nosuchfieldexception

My project brings in lot of inter-related dependencies. One of it needs httpclient-4.3.3 and apache cassandra-all brings in libthrift 0.9.1 which needs httpclient-4.2.5 version.

I'm trying to run a map reduce job and am seeing a FATAL message in the logs java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a new-bie to developing in hadoop/map-reduce/yarn environment. I found the issue. /hadoop/share/common/lib was having httpclient-4.2.5 and httpcore-4.2.5 jars. Replacing them with 4.3.3 jars solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right. `DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy` didn't contain the static field

```
public static final DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy INSTANCE = new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy();
```

in version 4.2.5